# Anyway to get Aptana PHP back with Aptana 1.5.1?

Tags: php, eclipse-pdt, aptana

I made a mistake uninstalling Aptana PHP as I didn't know PDT would suck as much...It's unable to accept my theme color files for PHP docs.

I know it's not a relevant question for this community, but I didn't know where else to go.

Please Help.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you switch to Aptana 2? It builds on PDT and should support the old Aptana PHP features. I had no trouble upgrading and installing it in my 3.5 Eclipse installation.

Comment: I am unable to install a color theme to my PHP files when I switch to PDT. I have no other problem, I am very used to the NightLion theme. All other formats are still the same with the amazing dark gray theme and PHP files are burning my eyes...

Please lemme know if you know how I can install a color file to PHP documents in PDT...

Thanks though for trying to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowledge Base: Downloading Aptana Studio 1.5.1 and Aptana PHP
https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/faqs/installing-aptana-studio/downloading-aptana-studio-151-and-aptana-php

Comment: You Sir, are the best...I tried online but I couldn't find all this anywhere...

Thank you so much...

Answer (score 0):

If you remove PDT from Aptana 2.x you can re-add Aptana PHP 1.1 Development (http://update.aptana.com/install/php/), you'll also get the code completion back.

To color in Aptana 2.0 ... you have to customize a combination of the editors, it's a bit of work I found but in the end I was able to replicate http://www.monokai.nl/blog/2006/07/15/textmate-color-theme/ (more or less)

Aptana -> HTML -> Colors

etc